# RedirectToAction. Views with a different layouts

Tags: layout, view, asp.net-mvc-5, redirecttoaction

I have two Views:

GuestView uses `"~/Views/Shared/_GuestLayout.cshtml";`
MemberView uses `"~/Views/Shared/_MemberLayout.cshtml";`

From a GuestView in a GuestController I want to redirect to an action of a MemberController:

```
public class GuestController: Controller
{   
    public ActionResult Login(Login login)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("MemberView", "Member");                
    }
}

public class MemberController: Controller
{        
    public ActionResult MemberView()
    {
        return View();                
    }
}
```

My problem is when the controller redirects, MemberView is nested in both layouts. One isnide another.

How to properly use RedirectToAction with a views with different Layouts ?

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

The problem was, that I used Ajax.BeginForm to update a div, which would contain a desirable view.